# Connection failed - activation of network connection failed - dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: networking, dual-boot, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I have a newly installed Ubuntu setup. It's installed in a system that's running Windows 10. I installed Ubuntu onto a new dedicated SSD. The install went fine, but I cannot connect to ethernet. I get an error which says `Connection Failed - Activation of network connection failed`. This happened when I accessed via live USB and after installation.

I did some searching and can see a bunch of people have had similar issues, but none of the fixes I have seen seem to work. I have tried:

1. Shutting down Windows rather than restarting
2. Disabling/re-enabling network connection
3. Disabling fast boot in Windows
4. Disabling Wake on Magic Packet (WOL) in Windows

The computer is a desktop, so I don't have any integrated wifi. I do have a TP Link wifi dongle, but from what I have found it doesn't support Ubuntu natively, and all guides assume access to the internet already before setting it up.

I also have tried live USBs for Pop!_OS, Linux Mint and Manjaro, and all have the exact same behavior for the networking.

Comment: how do you get internet? You may need to release dhcp address in Windows to be able to get it in the next OS. For me `ipconfig/release & net stop dhcp` worked.